# How to install a full version of Windows on a Hyper-v VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, license-key

I downloaded a Win iso image and used it to setup my VM on Hyper-V. I have created the VM by allocating about 25 Gb of space. But everytime I boot the VM, it looks for the CD/DVD drive and then loads it from the iso.

1. How do I go about running it as a full install?
2. Do I have to get a new Win-10 license key?

Tx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I downloaded a Win iso image and used it to setup my VM on Hyper-V. I have created the VM by allocating about 25 GB of space. But every time I boot the VM, it looks for the CD/DVD drive and then loads it from the iso.

It either sounds like you have not ejected the disk from the virtual drive or you did not actually install Windows 10 on the virtual HDD.

> How do I go about running it as a full install?

You configure the virtual machine to boot to the installation environment, you select the virtual HDD from within the virtual environment, and you go through the installation process.  There is nothing special you have to do in order to install Windows 10 on a Hyper-V Virtual Machine.  The installation process, for the most part, is automated until you are asked to configure your initial profile.

> Do I have to get a new Win-10 license key?

In order to run an instance of Windows, it must be licensed, if you already have a Windows 10 Retail license you can use that.  A Windows 10 license cannot be used on multiple systems, this means you cannot use the same license, on a physical machine and a virtual machine.